# How do I check how many occurrences there are in a list that match a certain condition in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

In a given list

`example = ["james:6823", "barry:8263", "henry:2344", "james2342"]`

How would I check how many times the name `"james"` has occurred on the above list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most pythonic way of counting matching elements in something iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157039/most-pythonic-way-of-counting-matching-elements-in-something-iterable)

Answer (score 3):

We could use a list comprehension approach:

```py
example = ["james:6823", "barry:8263", "henry:2344", "james2342"]
count = len([x for x in example if "james" in x])
print(count)  # 2
```

Comment: Or `sum("james" in x for x in example)` This does not require to materialize the list of matching items.

Comment: This would include all names containing "james", not only equal to "james". It would probably be better to split each string.

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you don't want to use list comprehension, you can use:

```
example = ["james:6823", "barry:8263", "henry:2344", "james2342"]

count = 0
for entry in example:
    if "james" in entry:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"""
To check how many times the name "james" occurs on the above list.  
For eg : Here, james:6823 will be considered as 1 item. Again, james2342 will also be considered
as an item. Hence, total 2 items.
"""

aa = ["james:6823", "barry:8263", "henry:2344", "james2342"]

res = sum(1 for x in aa if x.startswith("james"))

print(res) #2

"""
To check how many strings are equal to the name "james" occurs on the above list using split.
For eg : Here, james:6823 will be considered as 1 item. But, james2342 will not be considered.

"""
res1= sum(1 for x in aa if x.split(':')[0] == 'james')
print(res1) # 1
```

Comment: This would include all names starting with "james", not only equal to "james". It would probably be better to split each string